# Gradients of operations done in the tensorflow.data.Dataset.map() function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I have a data set which includes an X and Y part.  X needs to be turned into D before being input into a neural network.

I use the `tf.data.Dataset` class to do this:

```
# Making the place holders
X = tf.placeholder(shape=[n_samples, n_atoms, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(shape=[n_samples, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

# Creating the data set
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))

# Transforming X to D using the map function 
dataset = dataset.map(X_to_D)
dataset = dataset.batch(200)
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
batch_D, batch_Y = iterator.get_next()
```

Where the function `X_to_D` is a tensorflow function that takes the `X` and `Y` tensors as an input and returns the `D` and `Y` tensors.

`D` is then split in batches and used as input to the neural network. The output of the neural network is `Y_prediction`.

I need to obtain the gradients of `Y_prediction` with respect to `X`. However, when trying:

```
gradients = tf.gradients(Y_prediction, X)
```

an error occurs:

> LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: IteratorGetNext
>   LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'IteratorGetNext_1' (op
>   type: IteratorGetNext)

Question:
It seems that it is easy to obtain the gradients of `Y_prediction` with respect to `D`. But, how would I go about calculating the gradients of `Y_prediction` with respect to `X`?

Note:
The `X_to_D` function is very memory intense and can only be done on really small batches of the data. So I can’t create the data set, split it in batches and do the transformation from `X` to `D` just before each batch is used for training. This is because the batch size used for the training would be too large for making the `X` to `D` transformation.

Comment: You don't compute gradients with respect to `X` (your network inputs). You compute gradients with respect to the _variables_ in your model (neural network weights, biases etc.).

Comment: @xdurch0 I want the gradients with respect to the placeholder X. Normally this would work (see example https://gist.github.com/SilviaAmAm/b09a1a178fe34cf8f6c67d1d735919d5), but because of the tf.data.Iterator this doesn't seem to work. I am looking for a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

With tensorflow 2.0, you can write customize model and this allows you to compute derivative w.r.t. the input. For example,

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel,self).__init__(name = 'my_model')
        self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(32,activation = 'relu', input_dim=2)
        self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(64,activation=tf.sin)
        self.dense_3 = layers.Dense(1)
    def call(self, inputs):
        # Define your forward pass here
        x = self.dense_1(inputs)
        x = self.dense_2(x)
        return self.dense_3(x)

model = MyModel()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size = 1,
                    validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0)
```

To compute the derivative:

```
x = tf.constant(X_train[:1,:])
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(x)
    y = model.call(x)
dy_dx = g.gradient(y, x)
print(y)
dy_dx
```